# How do I get the answer from a VisualBasic Input Box in C#

Tags: c#

I have tried to make an InputBox in C#, I have managed to figure out how do this however, now I cannot extract an answer. Whenever I try to extract an answer it keeps coming up with the following error: "*Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.Windows.Forms.Label'*." The code I have written so far is below.

```
private void devBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bluePlyr1;
    bluePlyr1 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Name of Player 1");
    devLbl1 = bluePlyr1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's pretty basic, but a good opportunity to press this point, "What is the type of the left side?" and "What is the type of the right side?"

Answer (score 5):

Then I'm pretty sure that `devLbl1` is a [Label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label(v=vs.110).aspx)

do

```
devLbl1.Text = bluePlyr1;
```

Answer (score 1):

C#, unlike Visual Basic, does not have "default" properties. While your assignment of `devLbl1 = bluePlyr1` would work in VB (because `Text` is the default property of a label) it won't work in C#. You need to specify the property you're trying to set.

```
devlbl1.Text = bluePlyr1;
```